# Get Parameters of Window.Current.Content

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm wanting to access the parameters that were passed to the current page I'm viewing. I'm doing:

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
```

and I get the page type by doing:

```
rootFrame.CurrentSourcePageType
```

but how can I get the parameters that were passed to that page? I'm running this code in App.xaml.cs.

Thanks

Comment: I need more info. Can you post how you are sending the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the parameters in your `App.xaml.cs`, you can use the `Navigated` event to strip the parameters on every successful navigation. Simply add the event handler next to the `NavigationFailed` event.

```
rootFrame = new Frame();

rootFrame.Navigated += OnFrameNavigated;
rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
```

and write the event handler:

```
private void OnFrameNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    object parameter = e.Parameter;
}
```

If you need the parameter in your page, you can get it from the `OnNavigatedTo` method.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    object parameter = e.Parameter;
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I needed.